# Solve $(x^2-1)y''+6xy'+6y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solution:

$$
\begin{align}
\left(x^2-1\right) a^2&+6 x a+6=0 \\
x^2 a^2-a^2&+6 x a+6=0 \\
&\left\{\begin{aligned} 
x^2 \cdot a^2&=0 \\
6 x a&=0&  \implies  a&=0 \\
6-a^2&=0
\end{aligned}  \implies  \begin{aligned}
a=0 \\
a=2 \sqrt{6}
\end{aligned}\right. \\
\end{align}
$$
there is no solution in exponential form. Now we search for special solutions.

$$
\begin{array}{l}
y=e^{a x} . \\
y=x^n+\ldots \\
y^{\prime}=n\left(x^{n-1}\right)+\ldots \\
y^{\prime \prime}=n(n-1) \cdot x^{n-2}+\ldots
\end{array}
$$

$\begin{align}\left(x^2-1\right)\left(n(n-1) x^{n-2}+\ldots\right)+6 x n\left(x^{n-1}\right)+6\left(x^n\right)=0 \\ x^{n:} \quad n(n-1)+6 n+6=0 \\ n^2+5 n+6=0 \\ (n+3)(n+2)=0 \\ n=3, \quad n=2\end{align}$

I don't know what to do now.

Comment: Use power series method.

Answer (score 4):

Try substituting $u=(x^2-1)^2y$. Then you should get the equation $(x^2-1)u''-2xu' +2u=0$, which has simple polynomial solutions.